# Exit routine for blackberry - similar to MIDlet.destroyApp(boolean)

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is there an exit routine that will be called by the runtime every time a blackberry app signals that it wants to exit, similar to `MIDlet.destroyApp(boolean)` for traditional midlets?

If none exists, how do you ensure for instance that a particular task gets executed just before a blackberry app exits?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [onClose()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onClose%28%29) method

```
 public class MyMainScreen extends MainScreen {
        public MyMainScreen() {
            super();
        }
        public boolean onClose() {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
```

> ```
>   public boolean onClose()
> ```
>
> > Indicates a close event has occurred.
> >     The default implementation is
> >     activated by specifying DEFAULT_CLOSE.
> >     It will call onSavePrompt if the
> >     screen is dirty, then call close() if
> >     sucessful.